# How to remove consecutive duplicate commas from a php string

Tags: php, regex

How to remove consecutive duplicate commas in php.
Tried this piece of code. It works when there is no space before comma.

```
<?php
$a="test, , 1, , , 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY";
$my_string = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $a);
$string=trim($my_string);
echo $string;
?>
```

expeted output:

```
$a="test, 1, 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your regular expression to this: `(?:,\s*){2,}`

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/1vFhVb/2

#### Details

- `,\s*` means a comma followed by some spaces or not (includes tabs too).
- `(?:)` is just a non-capturing group because we want `,\s*` several times so we put it in a non-capturing group like this `(?:,\s*)` and then we can add the `{2,}` to say we want this 2 or more times.

We then replace it by `,`  (I added the space for readability).

```php
$result = preg_replace(
  '/(?:,\s*){2,}/',
  ', ',
  'test, , 1, , , 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY'
);

echo $result;
```

displays: `test, 1, 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY`

#### Edit (thanks to Markus)

As @MarkusAO mentionned, if your string is multiline then it's
necessary to replace the `\s` by `\h`, which is used to match
only horizontal spaces. This would lead to this regex: `(?:,\h*){2,}`

Secondly, what should we do with some comas at the beginning or the
end? Typically how would you handle this input?

```
Av. de Lavaux, 31, , , 1009 Pully, VD,
, 45, 3rd floor, , 8000 Zürich, ZH, Switzerland
Test, 8, , +41 77 800 80 80, , ,
, ,, the last test,, USA
```

Do we want to keep the trailing comma on the first line? Probably not. And commas at the beggining? Maybe not again. In this case we could add some cases to the regex to remove them:

- We'll use the multiline option with the `m` flag. This will let us match line beginnings with `^` and line endings with `$`.
- We'll use the `x` flag for extended notation so that we can put it on several lines for more readability. In this situation, spaces and new lines in the regex are ignored.
- To match commas and spaces at the beginning, it will be `^(?:\h*,\h*)+`. As we don't really know if there's spaces before or after the commas, we surround the comma char with `\h*`. Then, the whole group should be once or several times, this is why we put it in a non-capturing group with the `+` after it.
- To match commas and spaces at the end of a line, it will simply be `(?:\h*,\h*)+$`. It's the same as above but you put the `$` after the repeating commas.
- Now, to remove the duplicate commas in the middle, we'll use a different approach. Before we were looking for 2 or more commas to replace it by one comma. Now the idea is a bit different since we have to use an empty string in the replacement string for the beginning and ending commas handled above. So we'll remove commas only if they are in front of another comma. This can be done with the help of a positive lookahead:

  - We are looking for a comma and some optional spaces with `,\h*`.
  - a positive lookahead is done using the `(?=   )` syntax. We
    want to find commas and spaces again, so we'll put them inside
    and it will become `(?=,\h*)`.
  - putting it together: `,\h*(?=,\h*)`
- We want to match one of the 3 regex. This can be done with the `|`
  operator. And if we use the `x` flag mentionned above we can write
  it on several lines and add comments for readability:

  ```
  ^(?:\h*,\h*)+  # Leading commas
  |
  (?:\h*,\h*)+$  # Ending commas
  |
  ,\h*(?=,\h*)   # Commas followed by commas
  ```

Testing and playing: https://regex101.com/r/Gvu39h/4

PHP code would become:

```php
<?php

$pattern = <<<REGEX
/
^(?:\h*,\h*)+  # Leading commas
|
(?:\h*,\h*)+$  # Ending commas
|
,\h*(?=,\h*)   # Commas followed by commas
/mx
REGEX;

$input = 'Av. de Lavaux, 31, , , 1009 Pully, VD,
, 45, 3rd floor, , 8000 Zürich, ZH, Switzerland
Test, 8, , +41 77 800 80 80, , ,
, ,, the last test,, USA';

$replace = '';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $input);
```

It outputs the following:

```
Av. de Lavaux, 31, 1009 Pully, VD
45, 3rd floor, 8000 Zürich, ZH, Switzerland
Test, 8, +41 77 800 80 80
the last test, USA
```

Comment: In case we have a fringe case with leading and trailing commas in multi-line CSV data (as may happen), say, `test,, foo, bar,\n
,test,bar,,foo`, the `\s` (any space) will munch the two lines up into a single line, since it also matches vertical spaces, Use `\h` for horizontal space only. Example: https://regex101.com/r/dqclnC/1

Comment: Hi @MarkusAO! Thanks for this great idea. I didn't think about the fact that the input could be multiline. I'll correct the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Well you turned this into a full-on regex tutorial didn't you, great work! As for keeping trailing/leading commas, it seems they would only ever be significant in terms of the data structure, which OP doesn't seem to worry over.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with `array_map`, `array_filter` and `implode`:

```
<?php

$a = "test, , 1, , , 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY";

$explode = array_map(function ($e) {
    return trim($e);
}, explode(',', $a));

$filter = array_filter($explode);
$string = implode(', ', $filter);

echo $string . PHP_EOL;
```

Returns `test, 1, 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY`

Comment: Good idea to use explode/implode, but instead of trimming with array_map, simply use explode with `', '` (a comma + a space) as delimiter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I had that originally, but the issue is if there are consecutive commas without a space inbetween, they won't be removed

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to cross newlines that could be matched by `\s`:

```
,\h*,[\h,]*
```

- `,\h*,` Match `,` optional horizontal whitespace chars and another `,`
- `[\h,]*` Optionally repeat a character class matching either a `,` or horizontal whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LyxxiH/1)

```
$a="test, , 1, , , 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY";
$my_string = preg_replace("/,\h*,[\h,]*/", ", ", $a);
echo $my_string;
```

Output

```
test, 1, 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` or `explode` and `implode`.

If you have a string like `$a`, then you can simply use `str_replace`.

```
$a="test, , 1, , , 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY";
$my_string = str_replace(" ,","",$a);
$string=trim($my_string);
```

But if you have a string like `$b`, you have to use `implode` and `explode` to construct the new string. (Note the commas without leading spaces)

```
$b = "test, , 1, , ,,, 245 Park Avenue, New York, NY";

$strArray = explode(',', $b);

$myArray = [];
foreach ($strArray as $str){

    if (trim($str) != null || trim($str) != ""){
        $myArray[] = $str;
    }

}

$myStr = implode(',', $myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the shortest solution possible:

```
while(($b = str_replace(', ,', ',', $a)) != $a) 
     $a = $b;
```

But it works only if there are spaces between commas.

Comment: Instead of comparing the newest string with the old one, use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with its 4th parameter in a `do...while` loop and put the counter as the while condition.